# What is the difference between ~ and / in paths

Tags: shell, directory-structure

When I first log in to Unix on my Mac, I usually see a `~` after my username in the command line.

However, if I look at the apps contained in that directory `~/Applications` they are not all of my applications, but rather just some of my chrome apps.

If I `cd` to my `/` directory, and then go to `/Applications` there I see all of my applications, so I am wondering what is the difference?

Also, if I go to `~/MY-USERNAME/Applications` I see the same as if I just I were just in `~`. So what is the difference?

Lastly, how come I can `cd` into my `USERNAME` directory endlessly?  (see screen shot, "startec" is my username)

[image: my command line]

Comment: Also, for your last question, you have apparently created a symlink called `Startec` that points to your home directory. If you use `ls -l` you'll probably see an entry that shows either `Startec -> .` or `Startec -> /Users/Startec`.

Comment: Yes! That is it, I must have forgotten about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is your home directory, `/` is the root directory.
`~` is where you keep your personal files and directories. Other users can't see or access them. Files and directories in `/` are system-wide and accessible to all users who have the right permissions.

Startec is a link, which allows you to have two pointers to the same directory (in this case it points to your home directory). I know that most people draw the file system strictly as a tree, but with links (hard or soft) this isn't completely true.

To create links you can use the `ln` command. To see more about those see, `man 1 ln`.

Here is a diagram of a unix file system with links shown in dotted lines, and directories with solid lines.

[image: unix file system]

Source: http://users.aber.ac.uk/cwl/UNIX/notes/filesystem/fs.html

Comment: So my user directory (`~`) is under `usr` in this graph?  Also, when I run ls, I see `usr` but also `Users`, and am not sure of the difference.

Comment: Mac OS X uses different names than the image in the above answer. User home directories are under `/Users`.

Comment: Though, in the above graph, there should be an extra point under `/` called `home`. Under the `home` directory are users' `~` in many *nix OSs.

Comment: If I recall, Mac OS X has user directories under `/Users/user_name/`. If you `cd ~/`, then `pwd`, you can see what your file path is. That would be better than any of my guesses.